# I want to merge 2 image using foor loop and save in Document Directory "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" Error

Tags: ios, swift

I want to merge 2 image using foor loop and save in Document Directory.
 I have 1000 images so, how i can mearge images and save document Directory.
I call Below Function inside a for loop for get a 2 images for the mearge,then i want to return image save in Document Directory,That time got `"Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"` Error

```
private func processImage(imageFirst: UIImage, imageSecond: UIImage, size: CGSize, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)
            imageFirst.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            imageSecond.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.abc.size.height, width: size.width, height: self.abcd.size.height))
            let tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            completion(tempImage!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think for this type of loop you should use to non arc Project just because you hold your images in your memory

Comment: So,Can you tell me how to remove image memory and image save in document directory

Comment: As it stands, you're effectively loading 1000 images into memory simultaneously and then attempting to process them on a background queue (although the `sync` call really moots that effort and forces back to foreground queue)  Were it me, I'd queue up the file names and then on the background thread (using async instead of sync) I would explicitly load the files into UIImages and process them.  You'll still probably have memory issues though because of doing it all in parallel.  You may need to create an explicitly serial queue to use instead.